# Lazy Conditional Rule not doing anything! Why?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, .htaccess, rewritecond

I am rewriting php generated thumbnails with igly urls into nice ones. instead of `img.php?src=bla.jpg&w=200&h=100` the static filenames `IMG-file_w200_h100.jpg`

Because the rewrite is so complex and involves many variations, only urls starting with IMG- should be listening to the rewrite rule. The conditional first rule however doesnt seem to work: if i change it into IMF or something else, it still fires the rewrite rules! Any ideas as to why the conditional doesnt work?

```
# Rewrite imgcpu?src= thumbnail maker to nice static urls
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^IMG.*$
RewriteRule ^IMG-(.+)_w(.+)_h(.+)_f(.+).jpg$ imgcpu\?src=$1\.jpg&w=$2&h=$3&f=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^IMG-(.+)_w(.+)_q(.+).jpg$ imgcpu\?src=$1\.jpg&w=$2&q=$3 [L]
etc
```

Comment: Because it's lazy! Nyuk nyuk nyuk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RewriteCond` is actually processed *after* the `RewriteRule` matches! Here's a diagram from the [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/rewrite_tech.html):

[image: Rewrite Control Flow]

Comment: Thanks Dennis for the graph. So, if i understand correctly, there is no speed gain? it will check every single REwriteRule anywayz?

Comment: @Sam: No speed gain. If RewriteRules are `[C]` chained it won't go through all of *them*, though, it stops processing that group on the first failed match. RewriteCond is just for selecting whether a matching RewriteRule is applied. It's like short-circuit processing of `if (RW and RC) then ...` where the "RC" is only evaluated if the "RW" is true.

Comment: Hi Dennis, interesting. I see, its just another Does the entire chain group of rules apply to each of the files ( in this case images ) that want to be rewritten, right?  I did apply [C] on all except last rule with the unelegant reqritecode above but failed. should it be [C,L] or sometin else?

Comment: @Sam: Have you tried using `RewriteLog rewrite_log` and `RewriteLogLevel 9` and looking at the log so you can see what's happening?

Comment: @Dennis, thats very cool, some information on the errors would be highly valuable. How and where do i exactly set those in my htaccess?

Comment: @Dennis, a look into my current htaccess file: perhaps this will shed some light into the matter:  http://serverfault.com/questions/213191/does-is-matter-in-what-order-rules-are-placed-in-htaccess

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} %/IMG.*$ [NC]
```

Comment: Hello dmah, thanks for your suggestion, BUT, after changing the old cond to new cond, and changing `IMG` to `MUFFINTOPS` the rewrite rules still all fire correctly... i dont get it!